# How do I emulate auth multi-tenancy in firebase emulator with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am using firebase authentication multi-tenancy with the nodejs firebase-admin-sdk.

When i try creating an authentication tenant using the firebase emulator suite I get a 404 error. But same code works if i use my production firebase.

You can reproduce the error by running the code below in nodejs runtime. I am assuming you have firebase emulator running and you have a firebase project with service account configuration

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

process.env["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/serviceaccount.json" // replace with the path to your google cloud service account config
process.env['FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST'] = "localhost:9099" // firebase emulator auth port


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});


admin.auth().tenantManager().createTenant({
    displayName: 'Tenant123',
    emailSignInConfig: {
      enabled: true,
      passwordRequired: false, // Email link sign-in enabled.
    }
  })
  .then(newTenant => {
    console.log('new tenancy created', newTenant)
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: The issue still vague. Can you include in your question [how to produce your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question lacks details that can help generate good answers. Please read this guide and update your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for the feedback. i have tried to improve the question by adding more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Admin SDK supports Firebase Authentication Multi-tenancy. For testing purposes of Firebase products and services, we are using the Firebase Emulator with Firebase Admin SDK **but** Firebase Authentication Multi-tenancy support requires Google Cloud's Identity Platform (GCIP).

Therefore, we can't use the Firebase Authentication Multi-tenancy inside the Firebase Local Emulator because currently there's no feature of Multi-tenancy inside the emulator.

If you want to have this feature, you can file a [feature request in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features).

Comment: Thank you for your help. i will request the feature

Comment: @PrinceOmonuItanyi did you get a response about this being added as a feature?

Comment: I think this answer is outdated. as I can see tenants are now supported in my running local emulator